# Out of CaCO3 and MgCO3, which has higher electrical conductivity of molten solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, conductivity

According to me, Mg will be more hydrated and so should have lesser conductivity. Is that correct?

Comment: The 'hydration' makes this question very unclear.

Comment: This question needs to be fixed: neither carbonate is soluble in water and neither melts without decomposition to the respective oxide. If the question is about transport coefficients or whatever, it should ask that. Otherwise, the question should be on hold or closed.

Comment: "Molten solution" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EdV - but they do melt, just not at STP in air. For example https://www.geochemicalperspectivesletters.org/documents/GPL1813_noSI.pdf - Properties of molten CaCO3 at high pressure - important in earth sciences.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - would 'liquid solution' be better? Consider a mixture of liquid CaCO3 and MgCO3. I have no idea whether it would phase separate into two incompatible liquids or not.

Comment: @JonCuster Quite honestly, do you really think this is what the question is about? The OP should replace this with a well-formed question and title. Otherwise, it is just leading to non-productive mind reading.

Comment: @EdV - honestly I think the question is quite unclear, and have voted to close based on that. But, there seem to be a lot of assumptions and statements being made based on those assumptions. Yes, those compounds melt, and I bet the different ions in the melt have different mobilities.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really think molten inorganic salts will have a trace of water? Second question is do these carbonates melt? Don't mix molten state with aqueous state. No correlation.

When these compounds are heated both MgO and CaO are formed releasing carbon dioxide. They don't like to melt at all. Have you heard of limelight? This comes from CaO glowing brightly at high temperatures.

Comment: And the connection of this answer to conductivity is what, exactly?

Comment: The answer is basically reductio ad absurdum of the original query of molten calcium carbonate and magnesium carbonate. If someone can actually melt them without decomposition, then they should enlighten us. If molten means aqueous state, then it is another story.

Comment: You are thinking too narrowly, seemingly limiting your response to STP in air.

Comment: Consider papers such as http://www.electrochemsci.org/abstracts/vol13/131009771.pdf titled "Effect of Temperature and Voltage on the Preparation of Solid
Carbon by Electrolysis of a Molten CaCO3-Li2CO3-LiCl
Electrolyte"

Comment: Sure, interesting idea but that is a special case when we melt CaCO3 in a certain atmosphere or in the presence of other salts. The OP should clarify the question. It makes no sense as written. "Molten" is not compatible with "hydration."

Comment: I fully agree the 'hydration' suggests the question is unclear. But we do plenty of chemistry under non-STP conditions (and I don't want to be anywhere near molten CaCO3 or MgCO3 live and in-person).

Answer (score 0):

"Molten" here probably means "liquid".  While the carbonates gave too little solubility to be considered for electrolyte, we can compare the conductances of $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ in dilute solution.  In [this reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pubs.usgs.gov/wsp/2311/report.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiAiOaruLnkAhUQY6wKHQI8BTMQFjAIegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0J1bHw_pQF1NMDk8yfJmMl) from the USGS, conductances from various common ions are given and, indeed, calcium ion has a greater conductance than magnesium ion in solution.  But the difference amounts to only a few percent for the overall conductivity of a chloride salt solution at a given concentration.